# How can i build- angular2 cli project to cordova build android

Tags: angular, cordova

i am playing with angular-cli 2 project , i want to build it for android using `cordova build android` , How do i do that ?

This is my folder structure:
[image]

I create cordova apps using HTML , CSS , JS. I am getting started with angular2. I want to know how do we build this with cordova.

> Please do not refer IONIC, i am aware of that.

Answer (score 12):

so in your angular cli project, 
Generate build using

```
ng build --prod --base-href .
```

Now whatever comes in the dist folder, put it in your cordova's www folder, then generate apk/ipa using

```
cordova build android
```

To automate the process you can make change's here

1. to make sure that the dist goes in cordova's www folder, change the dist location in angular-cli.json & Point it to cordova's www folder

this part to be specific

```
"apps": [{
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist", //change this line to point to cordova's www folder.
```

2. To run ng build --prod --base-href . whenever we do a cordova build, write a hook in cordova like this

GIST Link : [Cordova -Angular CLI Hook](https://gist.github.com/marthakdk/48b6466f64e26b57a579567bf8d80a15)

Register this hook in config.xml like this

```
<hook type="before_prepare" src="hooks/buildApp.js"/>
```

EDIT :

--base-href command.

[image]

Comment: What i did earlier is, i copied everything from dist, kept it inside www, zipped it and uploaded on build.phonegap.com, i could only see `loading...` and nothing else.  and what is a hook by the way ??

Comment: so how did u build it ? based on your error the base-href is not set, make sure that u build using `ng build --base-href .`

Comment: hook is something which allows u to run custom process before cordova build, so say u run cordova build, so first it will run angular build & Then do a cordova build

Comment: I did `ng build -prod -aot` , created a new cordova project and placed all from dist inside www then did the `cordova build android`. I installed it and it is only showing `loading...` and nothing else. Please guide

Comment: you forgot the `--base-href .` parameter while building

Comment: it says - `The option '--href' is not registered with the build command. Run `ng build --help` for a list of supported options.`

Comment: its --base-href & Not --href. 
See edit.

whichever build u do, add this `--base-href .` dont forget the dot after -href.

Comment: Still showing same message, see here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzgwuptysbdwfgk/Screenshot%202017-06-14%2007.45.36.png?dl=0

Comment: u typed it wrong 1) there is no space between --base & -href its 1 single thing i.e --base-href  2) after --base-href do a space & Then add .

Comment: As guided i did but again it is showing same error , see here- https://www.dropbox.com/s/xp1j7olcu5j5aa8/Screenshot%202017-06-14%2008.19.52.png?dl=0

Comment: U missed second point...there is a space after href ...
--base-href then a space then a dot